# Designing Database for Long Forms in Rails & ActiveRecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, activerecord

I want to store complex form/questionnaire data but I'm having a hard time designing the database:

A User can create a new Exam. When creating an Exam, the user needs to choose from a template with 30 pre-set questions (and I want to store the answer to each of these questions in the database).

Purpose of the template is so that practitioners might want to run different exams (e.g. knee exam, arm exam, spine exam etc). So they create a new exam, choose a specific template. And each template has many questions

What's the best way to design this database? I started creating Exam, Template, and Question models, but then I got lost building the relationships.

Comment: please explain the purpose of template

Comment: Sorry, just added: Purpose of the template is so that practitioners might want to run different exams (e.g. knee exam, arm exam, spine exam etc). So they create a new exam, choose a specific template. And each template has many questions.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I ended up designing the database. I added a 4th "answers" model. This way, I can associate answers to questions, and questions to templates, and templates to exams.

Hope this helps someone

[image]

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :patients
  has_many :assessments
end

class Patient < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :assessments
end

class Assessment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :template
  belongs_to :patient
  has_many :questions, :through=> :template
  has_many :answers, :through=> :questions
end


class Template < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :questions
end


class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :template
  has_one :answer
end


class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```